# dictionary error update sequence length - django

Tags: python, json, django

I am getting the following error.

So I have a django project and I am trying to send a api call and print out the response of the api call in an html template. When I send the request, within the terminal, it prints a response 200 which means that the request was good. I am then passing in the response into a template in order to display the repsonse that was gathered. Does anyone know how to properly display a json response into a html file.

I am pretty sure the issue is coming from the response that I am getting and trying to pass and display as text

```
JSONDecodeError at /signup
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Exception Value:    
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py in _scan_once, line 118
Python Executable:  C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\Desktop\\opentab\\opentab',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 31 Aug 2017 01:23:09 +0000
```

I am going to attach my view and html template that I have right now to display the json response in an html file...

Here is the views.py

```
 def createUserSynapse(request):
    url = 'http://uat-api.synapsefi.com'
    headers = {
        'X-SP-GATEWAY' : 'client_id_asdfeavea561va9685e1gre5ara|client_secret_4651av5sa1edgvawegv1a6we1v5a6s51gv',
        'X-SP-USER-IP' : '127.0.0.1',
        'X-SP-USER' : 'ge85a41v8e16v1a618gea164g65',
        'Contant-Type' : 'application/json',
    }
    payload = {
        "logins":[
            {
                "email":"test@test.com",
            }
        ],
        "phone_numbers":[
            "123.456.7890",
            "test@test.com",
        ],
        "legal_names":[
            "Test name",
        ],
        "extras":{
            "supp_id":"asdfe515641e56wg",
            "cip_tag":12,
            "is_business":False,
        }
    }
    print(url)
    print(headers)
    print(payload)
    call = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    response = json.loads(call.text)
    print(call)
    return render(request, 'tabs/create_user_synapse.html', response)
```

and here is the template...

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Synapse API Call</h1>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <p>{{call}}</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'home_page' %}">Home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to call `.json` (To get a dictionary representation of the returned `JSON`) on the Response from `requests` Before passing it to the template in the `render` method. Instead of passing it in directly.

Something like this:

```
call = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

call = call.json()
```

Comment: The error is now different. I am getting the following error `JSONDecodeError at /signup
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Exception Value: 
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py in _scan_once, line 118` @danidee

Comment: Well that means your `API` isn't Returning JSON back. print out that value of `call.content` so we can see what it is (if it's not sensitive information)

Comment: there is two print call methods, after the initial call it is displaying `<Response [200]>`. there is another print call after `call = call.json()` that is not printing anything.... @danidee

Comment: sorry i meant `call.content`

Comment: so `call = call.content` instead of `call.json()` so the two full lines are `call = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers) ` and `call = call.content`  @danidee

Comment: No i meant `print(call.content)` to see what your `API` returns. It's obviously not `JSON` if not you won't be getting errors when you call `call.json()`

Comment: now i am getting `b'Running!'
<Response [200]>` so that means that there is no response right...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153309/discussion-between-danidee-and-omar-jandali).